# how to display date value into the textbox from opened window

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

when i click on link, a window opened with datetime picker, i want to select the date and display into one textbox using java script.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('TextBoxID').value = dtpValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `window.opener.document` to reference the 'parent' window, but you'll have to test this.